# Cannot connect to IIS 7 from localhost

Tags: iis-7

I cannot connect to the local IIS 7 using "http://localhost" in IE. "http://127.0.0.1" doesn't work either.

The strange thing is that if I add a binding on e.g. port 81, then I can reach "http://localhost:81". Also turning off the firewall on the local machine doesn't help. The site is reachable from the internet. The local requests don't seem to hit IIS (no entries in the IIS log files).

IIS is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 from behind a hardware firewall device.

Note that I'm a programmer, not a network administrator, so I'm having a hard time trouble shooting this.

Comment: What is the actual message displayed in the browser? Turning off the firewall on the local machine won't help, it needs to be turned off at the server to test it properly.

Comment: whats the output of this command in Powershell? 'netstat -ao | findstr LISTENING'

Comment: *(Note that I'm a programmer, not a network administrator, so I'm having a hard time trouble shooting this.)* +1 for that! Me, too!

Answer (score 2):

Open up IIS and navigate to your site (use the content view, not feature view) and find your default site, locate your default file (index.html or default.aspx) and right click and browse. What does this do? The chances are the default site is not pointing to the locations you mentioned but something like localhost/webiste so I would guess the path you're looking at is wrong.

[image]

If it still fails, please let me know why it fails (is there an error message)?

Comment: Dave, I have the exact same situation as *Wout*. I did what you just suggested, and it shows *This page can't be displayed*. I was actually told to list my problem on ServerFault, so it is here: [Cannot Get Ported Over Website to New Win2008 Server to Launch](http://serverfault.com/q/628196/20532) with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my situation, (however I set DisableStrictNameChecking=0): http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx

Comment: Please add the relevant content of the article to make a stand alone answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.